# Unpermitted parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json

I am using this method for adding a question (creating it thein assigning it to a quiz) but All fields are succesfully written except for choices (string array ) I don't know what is the problem.

## quizzes_controller.rb:

```
def add_question
                        question = Question.new(question_params)
                        if (current_instructor.quizzes.exists?(:id => params[:quiz_id]))
                                quiz = Quiz.find(params[:quiz_id])
                                if question.save
                                        quiz.questions << question
                                        render json: { success: true, data:{:question => question}, info:{} }, status: 201
                                else
                                        render json: { success: false, data:{}, :info => question.errors }, status: 422
                                end
                        else
                                render json: { success: false, data:{}, info:"Quiz is not found"}, status: 422
                        end    
end

private
def question_params
                        params.require(:question).permit(:text, :mark, :right_answer,{:choices => []})
end
```

## questions.rb:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
        serialize :choices,Array
        belongs_to :quiz
        validates :text, presence: true
        validates :right_answer, presence: true
end
```

curl -v  -H  'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -H "X-Instructor-Email: fakhr@example.com" #-H "X-Instructor-Token: gjE7xULgNLSorQgqr689"  -X POST http://localhost:3000/api/quizzes/addquestion/1 -d "
{\"question\":{\"text\":\"What is your name?\",\"mark\":\"10\",\"right_answer\":\"a\",\"choices\":\"[a,b,c,d]\"}}"

terminal:
The question is created and all attributes are written except for choices
{"success":true,"data":{"question":{"id":13,"text":"What is your name?","mark":10.0,"choices":
[],"right_answer":"a","quiz_id":1,"created_at":"2015-02-06T14:07:15.677Z","updated_at":"2015-02-
06T14:07:15.806Z"}},"info":{}}%

In the server I got:
Unpermitted parameters: choices

migration:

```
class CreateQuestions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :questions do |t|
      t.text :text
      t.float :mark
      t.text :choices
      t.string :right_answer
      t.belongs_to :quiz, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Can we see your migration? I have had a similar problem with initiating a `string` column as an array via `serialize`. My solution was to change the column type to `text`.

Comment: ok, so I recreated your app here: https://gist.github.com/dimanyc/0d77f4b889bc2004351e. Column type looks fine. @Stanislav Mekhonoshin was right about wrapping `choices` into hash. No need for that. Just leave your strong params as is: `params.require(:question).permit(:body, :mark, :choices, :right_answer)`, and add `serialize :choices, Array` to the Model. See my gist. Let me know.

Comment: It could be solved without changing anything the problem was in the curl command

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
params.require(:question).permit(:text, :mark, :right_answer, choices:[])
```

Why did you wrap it into hash?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether to put in a hash or not, the same error appears. In rails 4 we should use a hash.